# Permanently install Sideloading Windows Store apps

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, sideloading

I´ve developed an windows app and installed it on a few windows8 devices.

During the installation, I have to sign in with my microsoft account and I get the message that i have to repeat that after 6 month.

Now I have the requirement that the app runs permanently on this devices without signing the microsoft account every 6 month.

I found this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx) with this note:
*When the user attempts to open an app that requires a developer license, the user is prompted to renew the license if it has expired. This step requires the user to sign in to their Microsoft account.*

Can I install the app without a developer license?

Is the solution for my problem the Enterprise sideloading? (How does this works?)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right you have to publish the application in the Windows App Store to be installable without a developer license.

If you don't want that I don't think there is another solution except for rewriting the program as a normal desktop application

Comment: Is there no opportunity to install the company-intern apps on our devices without App Store. I read some articles in the web, but I didn´t found a concret concept for that.
(Keyword: Enterprise sideloading?)

Comment: I have to point out that I never heard of "Enterprise sideloading" but it sounds interesting. At the moment this link (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388) is all I can give you related to Enterprise sideloading. Maybe It's usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. Use Windows Store

   > No license or anything just upload the package even via visual studio.
2. Sideloading

   > You can use Windows Intune to do that, but you need to buy the sideloading    key which going to cost you around 100$ but can be used on unlimited no of devices.
   >   [Look here for more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micham/2014/05/30/sideloading-store-apps-to-windows-8-1-devices/)

You can manually install via command prompt without using Intune but remember buying that sideloading key is a must.

NOTE: Heard about the private store concept? Using Windows Intune you can do that. So just like "Windows Store" app you have another app called "Company Portal" and that will behave as private store, which contains only apps you developed and deployed.